# When nilradical belongs to a Gabriel filter

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Recall that a Gabriel filter of ideals $\mathscr{I}_\sigma$ of a commutative ring $R$ is a non–empty filter of ideals satisfying that every ideal
$I$ of $R$, for which there exists an ideal $J\in\mathscr{I}_\sigma$  such that $(I : j):=\{r\in R\mid rj\in I\}\in\mathscr{I}_\sigma$ , for every
$j\in J$, belongs to $\mathscr{I}_\sigma$. Now let $\mathscr{I}_\sigma$ be a Gabriel filter of ideals of a commutative ring $R$ such that $Nil(R)\in \mathscr{I}_\sigma$, where $Nil(R)=\{r\in R\mid r^n=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Can we deduced that $\langle 0\rangle\in\mathscr{I}_\sigma$?